# Newly replaced shock absorbers fail

Tags: shock-absorber

What causes both of them to fail? I think they were installed wrong. How can this happen? I saw absorbers with much oil leaking on them also.

Comment: can be damaged due to incorrect install, bend or poorly made

Comment: If you have missing rubber bump stops, you could over compress and damage them.